# Table-view not display data in Angular Js

Tags: angularjs

I am beginner for angular-js and I want to display data in table using the below code and I followed the below link, but the table-view data is not showing.

What did I do wrong_

Can some one help me please?

https://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/

### index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body  ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<table st-table="rowCollection" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>first name</th>
        <th>last name</th>
        <th>birth date</th>
        <th>balance</th>
        <th>email</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in rowCollection">
        <td>{{row.firstName}}</td>
        <td>{{row.lastName}}</td>
        <td>{{row.birthDate}}</td>
        <td>{{row.balance}}</td>
        <td>{{row.email}}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

### app.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',['smart-table']);
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function (scope) {
    scope.rowCollection = [
        {firstName: 'Laurent', lastName: 'Renard', birthDate: new Date('1987-05-21'), balance: 102, email: 'whatever@gmail.com'},
        {firstName: 'Blandine', lastName: 'Faivre', birthDate: new Date('1987-04-25'), balance: -2323.22, email: 'oufblandou@gmail.com'},
        {firstName: 'Francoise', lastName: 'Frere', birthDate: new Date('1955-08-27'), balance: 42343, email: 'raymondef@gmail.com'}
    ];
}]);
```

Comment: have you added the references for smart-table.js?

Comment: npm install angular-smart-table

Comment: you need to refer the js file

Comment: i used above command

Comment: can you put your code on plunkr

Comment: even if you have used, thats for installation. you need to refer the installed file

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/OGq29V?p=preview

Comment: above link there is smart-table.debug.js do i have to add that file in my project?

Comment: I can see the plunkr displayed the data :(

Comment: @Krish data is visible in the table!!! in the plnkr link provided by you, but in the code you have provided, you forgot add $ to the scope.

Answer (score 0):

Your dependencies injection is wrong in your `app.js`.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',['smart-table']);
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.rowCollection = [
        {firstName: 'Laurent', lastName: 'Renard', birthDate: new Date('1987-05-21'), balance: 102, email: 'whatever@gmail.com'},
        {firstName: 'Blandine', lastName: 'Faivre', birthDate: new Date('1987-04-25'), balance: -2323.22, email: 'oufblandou@gmail.com'},
        {firstName: 'Francoise', lastName: 'Frere', birthDate: new Date('1955-08-27'), balance: 42343, email: 'raymondef@gmail.com'}
    ];
}]);
```